# Calculate 3D rotation between two vectors of acceleration in Android

Tags: android, vector, 3d, accelerometer

I am creating app that will measure acceleration of vehicle in each axis using accelerometer in Android smartphone. I need somehow rotate phone measurement coordinations system to coordination system of vehicle - to allow driver to put phone in holder - and so phone will have some different rotation to vehicle.

I started with calibration process where I tell user to hold phone to match vehicle coordination system - so I save TYPE_GRAVITY sensor X, Y, and Z gravity acceleration value. Then I tell user to put phone in holder and again save TYPE_GRAVITY sensor X, Y, and Z gravity acceleration value.

Now I need to find some relation between those two vectors so I can use it to correct (rotate) TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION X,Y,Z data to match vehicle coordinations system.

Answer (score 0):

Using just a gravity sensor you'll lack one rotational axis to compute what you want.

Imagine your phone being held vertically, the accelerometer will show you direction to the bottom of the phone. If you now rotate it around vertical axis - you'll still get the same result from the accelerometer. This means you can't get the rotation around vertical axis this way.

One solution would be to use a gyroscope - this gives you entire rotation of the phone, but increases a hardware requirements of your app.

But the better solution IMHO would be to get rid of the entire calibration process. Cars move mostly straight, only sometimes you get the side way acceleration so you could scan your readings for few seconds and find a 'main' axis and a 'side' one.

Besides, your calibration process still depends on user precision during placing the phone, so it may not work as you've expected.